# if 2 vector spaces whose different dimensions are these isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If we have two finite-dimensional vector spaces whose dimensions are not equal. Can these vector spaces be isomorphic? Thank you.

Comment: What does isomorphic mean to you?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if $f\colon V\to W$ is an isomorphism, then $f$ maps a basis of $V$ to a basis of $W$.